# Transfer share a folder between two servers running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04

Tags: networking, server, samba, vpn

I have two servers both running Ubuntu 16.04. One is a proliant DL380 G7 annd the other is a proliant DL360 G7. The DL360 is connected to a VPN router. The DL380 is connected to a switch that the VPN router is connected to. There is an Ethernet cable between the DL380 and the DL360. I am trying to set it up so that when files get added to a specific folder on the DL360 (Connected to VPN router) they transfer to a folder on the DL380 preferably via the direct Ethernet. I've gotten it working with samba through the direct ethernet, however I cannot get it to connect to the VPN internet. I need it download all files through the VPN and transfer the files that are downloaded to the other server. Below is a picture of the network layout. Thank you for your help!

[Network Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhaI8.png)

Comment: Can you please add some captions to the diagram? More specifically, how the networks are set up.

Regardless of that a possible solution would be a combination of "cron" and "rsync" if you do not need the files to by synced immediately.